# Variable change $t$ to $\tau$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

I derived this differential equation, $\ddot{z}(t)+ (\beta(t) - \frac{1}{4}\alpha^2)z(t) = 0$, where $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta(t)$ is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{t\to\infty} \beta (t) = \beta$ a constant $> 0$. Now I need to derive a ODE for $z(\tau)$, where $\tau = \omega t$. $\omega $ is a constant such that $\omega ^2 = \beta - \frac{1}{4}\alpha^2$. All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say 'derive' i am assuming you mean, in this instance, simply determine the ODE under the change of variables(?). If so then let $T=wt$ , hence $\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{dz}{dT}\frac{dT}{dt}=w\frac{dz}{dT}$  and likewise $z''\left( t \right)={{w}^{2}}z''\left( T \right)$. One has therefore
$${{w}^{2}}z''\left( T \right)+\left( \beta \left( T \right)-\tfrac{1}{4}{{\alpha }^{2}} \right)z\left( T \right)=0$$

Comment: Yes I did simply mean the change of variables. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: can you show the chain rule details of how you got that expression for $z^{\prime\prime}(t)$?